# Unexpected EditText behavior

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext

So basically I know SQLite and stuff and I am used to it but somehow implementing data dynamically doesn't work either way. Here is my code..

```
package com.example.perfactlistview;

import junit.framework.Test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MySQLiteHelper db=new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    EditText fac_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_fac_name);
    EditText message=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_message);

    final String fac_name_store;
    final String message_store;
    fac_name_store=fac_name.getText().toString();
    message_store=message.getText().toString();


    Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            /*db.addMessages(new Faculty(fac_name_store, message_store));*/

            Log.d("ROW ADDED", "FACULTY name= "+fac_name_store+" FACULTY MESSAGE = "+message_store);

        }
    });





}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I know its a silly question but still i can't figure it out. Thanks in advance..

And one more thing `SQLiteHelper` and `Faculty` class (which are base for a sqlite database) are perfect and error less.(As I used this method a lot).

When I enter the data in `EditText` they don't get saved in their corresponding `String` Variables `fac_name_store` and `message_store` so I cant put data in my database table using edittext..

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes When i type data in edit text and hit Submit button. they dont get saved.

Comment: Why is `/*db.addMessages(new Faculty(fac_name_store, message_store));*/` commented?

Comment: Actually just for checking logs I have commented it. But it forgot to remove comment my mistake

Comment: But where is code to add row? `addMessages` and `Faculty` constructor?

Comment: Thanks For your Response.I really Appreciate it. But Rafet T's method worked for me. And FYI. I commented that portion. and just loged it. so no extra data get inserted in my table. and  'addMessages' method is for adding data in table and 'Faculty' is a name of table and base method for DATABASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try your first Problem like this:

```
package com.example.perfactlistview;

import junit.framework.Test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button mSubmitButton;
    EditText fac_name;
    EditText message;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MySQLiteHelper db=new MySQLiteHelper(this);

    fac_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_fac_name);
    message=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_message);

    Button submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            /*db.addMessages(new Faculty(fac_name_store, message_store));*/

            Log.d("ROW ADDED", "FACULTY name= "+fac_name.getText().toString() +" FACULTY MESSAGE = "+message.getText().toString());

        }
    });    
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Perfectly Worked thanks.. can you tell me why my code didn't work ?? is is not possible to store each individual item in an string type variable?? Anyway thanks again @RafelT

Comment: it is, but you are doing it in `onCreate`, and are "saving" the value too early (before you are able to enter Text there). You basically want the value, when the `onClick` event appears, not earlier. Feel free to accept this answer to mark it as solved :)

Comment: Thanks a Lot Man. I appreciate your answer really helped.. And Sorry actually i forgot to marked it as a right answer. Now I have.